# How to load a custom product attribute into a quote item?

Tags: magento

I'm developing a custom shipping method for Magento. For this shipping method I need to set a custom product attribute (airfreight_allowed). The shipping method checks whether the custom attribute is set to true for all products.

I have added the product attribute with an install script:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'airfreight_allowed', array(
'input'         => 'select',
'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'
...
));
```

In the shipping module I access the quote items like this:

```
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {   /* Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_request */
    if($item->getAirfreightAllowed() != 1)
        return false; /* Airfreight not allowed */
}
```

But the quote item doesn't contain the airfreight_allowed attribute. How can I add the airfreight_allowed attribute to the quote item? And how do I make sure this attribute contains the value of the corresponding product attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to your module's config.xml:

```
<global>
  <sales>
     <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <airfreight_allowed />
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
  </sales>
</global>
```

Set the attribute's property "used in product listing" to true.

Then you can access the attribute like this:

```
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {   
    if($item->getProduct()->getAirfreightAllowed() != 1)
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help to set the above in Magento 2 ?