# How to get custom attribute in Subtotal.php?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've got a problem with getting custom attribute in

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php**

for example $product->getPrice() or $product->getTaxClassId() works fine, but if I try my custom attribute $product->getBrutto() ('brutto' is my attribute) it doesnt work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are you writing an extension or doing front-end work? That's a core file...

Comment: just trying to change the way the prices are calculated and i need to multiply $product->getPrice() with(*) $product->getBrutto()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the custom attributes into the config.xml of your module, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267244/how-to-load-a-custom-product-attribute-into-a-quote-item):